# React.js - page need to refresh after axios call

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have code not show me the result after do action

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://ahmed-radi-bank-system-api.herokuapp.com/all`)
    .then(response => (setTransaction(response.data)))
},[])
```

if add transaction to `useEffect` I get a lot of rendering as you can see in console

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://ahmed-radi-bank-system-api.herokuapp.com/all`)
    .then(response => (setTransaction(response.data)))
},[transaction])
```

[image]

Comment: ideally, you can use the `transaction` state to show the new result. Because whenever you do an API call and refresh the page it will do the same continuously.

refreshing the page can be handled by adding this:
` window.location.reload(false);`

Let me know if I understood the question correctly

Comment: thank you for the comment, I will clarify what I need, now I have an API call I want after this call refresh the page to display the new result

Comment: Are you receiving something from your api call?

Comment: yes, I receive data but it appears after I go back then go to the page again because if I refresh the page directly I get error

Comment: you can this video to know what I mean it just 30 sec https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BwOcRONBylZJARaq4qAC_DEShtiefMKz?usp=sharing
refresh page problem it appears in last 5 sec it the second problem I have

Comment: I solved the problem in the last 5 seconds now I only have one problem when sending data I need to refresh the page to see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is: in `useEffect` if you put an object as a dependency you must specify one prop from this object to make `useEffect` stop the infinity loop

example of Infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Infinite loop!
  setObject({
    ...object,
    prop: 'newValue'
  })
}, [object]);
```

example of No infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
  // No infinite loop
  setObject({
    ...object,
    prop: 'newValue'
  })
}, [object.whenToUpdateProp]);
```

reference: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Pass an argument to the useEffect array, is your case the transaction variable. When it changes the data should rerender.

Check the documentations: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: yes, I do that but useEffect steel rendering does not stop

Comment: see the video to know what I mean: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ihSZoPAm-qgsRQbOx-nHaOOoWAqOx4Pd?usp=sharing

Comment: could you please upload to codesandbox? I guess there is a wrong function call somewhere that triggers rendering

Comment: this is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-leftpad-mzy4rm

Comment: path `useEffect`
1 - client/src/components/Alltransaction/Alltransaction.js
2 - client/src/components/Transaction/Transaction.js

Comment: onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitForm)} -> onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmitForm)}, please try it

Comment: Not work unfortunately and make the page refresh thanks for trying